# PHP require_once variable scope

Tags: php

Consider below scenario -

**File : array.php**

```
<?php
    $array1 = array();
    $array1['name'] = "Adam";
    $array1['gender'] = "Male";
    $array1['age'] = 34;
```

**File : file1.php**

```
<?php 
    function printArrayContent(){
        require_once 'array.php';
        var_dump($array1);
    }
printArrayContent();

include_once "file2.php";
```

**File : file2.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once "array.php";
    echo "File 2";
    print_r($array1);
```

When I run file1.php I get below output -

**OUTPUT**

```
array(3) {
 'name' =>
 string(4) "Adam"
 'gender' =>
 string(4) "Male"
 'age' =>
 int(34)
}
File 2PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: array1 in /private/tmp/file2.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /private/tmp/file1.php:0
PHP   2. include_once() /private/tmp/file1.php:11

Notice: Undefined variable: array1 in /private/tmp/file2.php on line 4

Call Stack:
 0.0212     230512   1. {main}() /private/tmp/file1.php:0
 0.0226     232424   2. include_once('/private/tmp/file2.php') /private/tmp/file1.php:11
```

Why am I not able to access `$array1` in `file2`? What is the solution for this (except storing `$array1` in `$GLOBALS` variable)?

Comment: how about just say : `include`?

Comment: `include` will work as expected. But, let's just say I need that variable `$array1` in 100 different files. Is there no other way than `include`ing it in all 100 files? Because `include` will read and parse the file again.

Comment: You can code OOP and go for autoloading OR you can use php.ini auto.prepend to include a file always OR you have to include it in all 100 files.

Comment: `except storing $array1 in $GLOBALS variable` you can use a type of registry instance that holds global API data (not global variables)

Answer (score 1):

require_once includes **ONCE** a same file. Since your already have included it in your `file1.php`, PHP engine does not include it another time in your `file2.php` and so you don't have access to the variables in your file2.php scope.